# Convert MBR to GPT

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm following [THIS](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) article to convert MBR to GPT, but when I give a command **p**, it doesn't list any disks:

[image]

What is wrong?

Note: I had dual boot with ubuntu and windows 7, I wanted to upgrade win7 to win 8.1, so I deleted the win7 partition.

Structure I had:

- C: Windows
- D: Linux
- E: Personal Files ( Important )

1> Would converting to GPT the above way erase the data in **E:**? (I need to convert to GPT so that I can install Win8 without hampering Ubuntu and Personal Data)

2> How can I fix the error in image

Comment: Was system originally Windows 8 and therefore UEFI/gpt. And you installed Windows 7 without converting its installer to UEFI and it (incorrectly) converted drive to BIOS boot and MBR. Windows when converting like that leaves backup gpt table which would be your old original install's partition table.  Choose the MBR using gdisk and see if it shows all your partitions. Then convert that.

Answer (score 9):

Note: I'm the author of `gdisk`.

Your disk's partition table is damaged. It looks like the disk had used the GUID Partition Table (GPT) format, but somewhere along the line, a GPT-unaware tool converted the disk from GPT to the Master Boot Record (MBR) format. The result is a valid MBR with leftover GPT backup data at the end of the disk. Given the `gdisk` output you've shown, it looks like the GPT data defines no partitions, so it's useless -- and even if it showed partitions, if my hypothesis is correct, those partitions would be invalid. Chances are you want to use the MBR data. This would be option #1 at the prompt for which partition table type to use in the screen shot you've shown; however, `gdisk` will then do an MBR-to-GPT conversion, which may not be the best approach for you....

You say you want to convert from MBR to GPT, but you don't say why you want to do this. The only hint in your question is that you also want to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1. Both versions of Windows are happy with either partition table type, so the Windows upgrade does not necessitate a partition table change. That said, both versions of Windows also tie their partition table type (MBR vs. GPT) to their boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI). Thus, if you change from MBR to GPT, you'll also necessarily change your boot mode -- but this change will not be automatic. In fact, changing the boot mode might not even be possible; most computers sold prior to late 2011 have BIOS firmware that cannot boot in EFI mode. If you bought your computer in late 2011 or 2012, it probably has EFI firmware that can boot in either way, but these early EFIs were often buggy and might boot better in BIOS mode. OTOH, the more recent the computer, the more likely it is to work well booting in EFI mode. Also, booting in EFI mode can be faster and more reliable. (See [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject.)

Note also that converting from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting will require you to change your Ubuntu boot loader. (You might continue to use GRUB 2, if that's what you're using now; but you'd have to replace the BIOS-mode GRUB 2 with an EFI-mode GRUB 2.) [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is generally the easiest way to do this, but it's imperative that you boot whatever emergency disk you use to run Boot Repair in the appropriate target mode -- that is, in BIOS mode if you want to install a BIOS-mode GRUB or EFI mode if you want to install an EFI-mode GRUB.

In sum, you should let your boot-mode needs lead the way on what to do:

- **BIOS-mode** -- If you choose to continue booting in BIOS mode, you should be able to launch the Windows 8.1 installer *in BIOS mode* and install it normally. Windows will likely take over the boot process, so you'll need to use Boot Repair (or a manual procedure that does much the same thing) to re-install a BIOS-mode GRUB. To avoid confusion, you may want to run `sudo sgdisk -z /dev/sda` from an Ubuntu emergency disk or after installation. (Note that's a *lowercase* `-z`; an uppercase `-Z` will wipe the MBR data, too, which is something you *don't* want to do!) This will wipe out the stray GPT data structures. (It will also wipe out part of GRUB, so you'll likely have to re-run Boot Repair after you do this.)
- **EFI-mode** -- If you want to switch to EFI mode, you should first verify that your computer is capable of booting in this way. If it can, I recommend disabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support in your firmware. You can use `gdisk` to convert from MBR to GPT, but tell it to read the existing MBR data at the screen you've shown. With that conversion complete, launch the Windows installer *in EFI mode* to install Windows; then use Boot Repair or [install my rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) to get Ubuntu booting in EFI mode.

In either case, it's critical that you understand how to control your computer's boot mode. This is a detail that's controlled by the firmware, not by the OS, and how to control it varies from one computer to another. See [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details on this.

One more caveat: It's possible that I've misdiagnosed your disk's current state. (I'm making inferences based on incomplete data.) If so, or if you make mistakes, you could end up making matters significantly worse. Thus, I advise proceeding with caution. If possible, do a complete low-level backup of your disk, as in `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/big/disk/sda.img`. This will give you a path to recovery should you make a change that proves to be destructive.

Comment: Thank You for answering. Just for info, I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 running fine on my machine, the problem came when I wanted to upgrade Windows to 8.1. And there all the problems started. [ISSUE IMAGE](http://i42.tinypic.com/28l0rq.gif). I had to format my system as a whole :-(

Answer (score 1):

Converting does not erase data. 
`Testdisk` should be able to recover the partitions.

Run `testdisk`. and scan for partitions.
Select the partitions to restore that resemble the ones you had.
This may convert you back to MBR.
If it does, look for a different guide.
The guide you are following does not preserve partitions.

Note: your ubuntu installation is going to need to be converted to EFI mode after you have installed win8.

Comment: TestDisk is likely not the best solution. It might work, but it's probably overkill for this situation, and if the disk has been repartitioned multiple times, TestDisk might detect long-unused partitions and try to restore them, which could be confusing or even destructive. Chances are the MBR partition table is fine and it simply needs to be used, either as an MBR partition table or converted to GPT by `gdisk`, as described in my answer.

Comment: @RodSmith - testdisk doesn't restore anything that you don't tell it too. the first scan only brings up recent deletions. reads MBR record I think. Long deleted partitions only show if you tell it to do a deeper scan, (a surface scan)

Comment: **"Converting does not erase data"** didn't help me, I lost my E: drive partition. I could only see single unallocated 1TB space with no partitions as partition table was replaced. Had to format the system as a whole :-(